# Maximise the sum of difference of adjacent elements

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer N. We need to find out the PermutationSum where PermutationSum for integer N is defined as the maximum sum of difference of adjacent elements in all arrangement of numbers from 1 to N.

Example Let N=3 then answer is 3

Explanation : For N=3, possible arrangements are :

```
{1,2,3} 
{1,3,2} 
{2,1,3} 
{2,3,1} 
{3,1,2} 
{3,2,1}
```

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {1,2,3} is 2 i.e abs(1-2)+abs(2-3)=2

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {1,3,2} is 3.

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {2,1,3} is 3.

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {2,3,1} is 3.

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {3,1,2} is 3.

Value of PermutationSum for arrangement {3,2,1} is 2.

So the maximum value of PermutationSum for all arrangements is 3.

We need to find this maximum value for given N where N is upto 100000.

I have N! solution. But it won't work for large N.

Comment: I would guess that there is a combinatorial solution which is much easier; basically, it makes sense to put elements with large difference next to each other, such that individual summands are maximized - just an idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graham Cormode gives a solution in [A047838](https://oeis.org/A047838): the answer is exactly floor(N^2/2 - 1).

Comment: Would it be possible to come up with all the different permutations that lead to the highest sum?

Comment: @AseemSharan Graham Cormode gives one permutation which gives this sum in his proof here: https://oeis.org/A047838/a047838.txt I don’t know, in general, how many others there might be or how to list them.